# When to use range function in python for loops

Tags: for-loop, nested-for-loop

If we are able to create a for loop without using the range function, as in:

```
foods = [potato, pizza, spinach]

for food in foods:
  print(food)
```

why am I not able to do the same in this following nested for loops?

```
def exponents(bases, powers):
  results = []

  for i in range(len(bases)):
    for j in range(len(powers)):
      results.append(bases[i]**powers[j])
  return results
```

rather using this approach:

```
def exponents(bases, powers):
  results = []

  for i in bases:
    for j in powers:
      results.append(bases[i]**powers[j])
  return results
```

will result in an indexError:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is the difference between the single and nested for loops in regards to these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the range function, you are iterating the list index. When you use the list directly, you are iterating the objects in the list.

Try this:

```
def exponents(bases, powers):
  results = []

  for b in bases:
    for p in powers:
      results.append(b**p)
  return results  # not new
```